# Youtube Preload limit?

Tags: youtube

I have enabled Preloading for my Watch Later playlist.  This currently contains 23 hour-long Google IO videos but YouTube seems to only ever preload up to 2 of them, never any more.

I have an HTC One X with over 24GB of space - I have to remove a video from the playlist that has been downloaded to allow another to begin.

Everywhere I search gives no details about limits on how much you can preload so I was wondering if anyone else knows anything about this or has seen anything similar?

Answer (score 6):

The queue limitation, AFAIK is [200 videos](http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!category-topic/youtube/how-to-use-youtube-features/t3r1f2UD9sA):

> You can queue up a maximum of 200 videos in a Watch Later list. The same limitation applies for any created playlist.

**Note:**
Make sure that you're preloading videos having the device charging and with an active Wi-Fi connection, in order to have them correctly preloaded to your phone.

---

### YouTube Instructions for a successul preload

According to the [YouTube Blog](http://youtube-global.blogspot.pt/2012/06/take-your-channels-with-you-on-new.html), it's mentioned that the preload process works if the phone is charging and a Wi-Fi connection exists:

> you can now preload and temporarily cache videos from your subscribed channels on your phone anytime it’s charging and your WiFi is connected. Just enable “Preloading” in the Settings menu. You’ll still need a connection to play the video, but once you do it’s smooth sailing through the latest from your subscribed channels and Watch Later queue.

Additionally, you need to have an active connection when pressing the play button.

Comment: OP, is already successfully preloading. He wants to know how many of the videos will it preload and how much of each video.

Comment: @roxan I've added the limit (200)! As soon as I find out the official link I'll update the answer. While I still believe that we aren't talking about a limit, since 2 is way far from 200, the issue appears to be the preload process going wrong!

Comment: As I understand it, the OP is preloading a single 24 hours video and the preloader is stopping stop at 2 hours, the limit you're writing is the limit on the number of videos.

Comment: @LieRyan "contains 23 hour-long Google IO **videos** but YouTube seems to only ever preload up to **2 of them**" <--- My interpretation is that he has 23hours of videos (plural), and only two get preloaded.

Answer (score 3):

I remember reading on one of the Google forums that there was a also a total size limit, and that the developer was going to ask the team if the limit could be extended. In my experience the limit seems to be around the 200-300 Megabyte mark.

Comment: A link to the forum would be nice if you could dig it out.

Comment: I think [this](http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/youtube/A8uWnURiqwg) is the link Luckyman mentioned. The Google guy never showed up again, though.